# Routing constraints for multiple controllers under top level route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, constraints, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for some feedback on both the philosophy of good practice and technical practice of using a top level route that routes to multiple Models based on conditions.

I need to have a top level route `domain.com/:id` that either routes to a: **Company** or **User**.

The condition/identifier being that a User has an `@` in the url, e.g. `domain.com/@theminijohn`

My routes for the moment look like this:

```
devise_for :users, path: '',
  path_names: {
    sign_up: '',
    registration: 'signup',
    sign_in: 'login',
    password: 'password',
    confirmation: 'verification'
  },
  controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks',
    passwords: 'users/passwords'
  }

resources :users, path: '', only: [:show] do
  member do
    get 'reviews', to: 'users#reviews', as: :reviews
    get :following, :followers
    post :follow, to: 'users#follow_user'
    post :unfollow, to: 'users#unfollow_user'
  end
end

resources :companies, path: '', only: [:show], as: :company do
  resources :products, path: '', only: [:show], as: :product
end
```

---

Furthermore the `@` sign will only be used in the url, aka it is not present in the attribute.

How do I go about this ?

**Edit:** Here's where I am:

the constraint that gets called from the route for the `:users` resource

```
module Constraints
  class UserProfile
    def matches?(request)
      if request.path.include?('@')
        slug = request.path.delete('/@')
        User.where(slug: slug).exists?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and in the controller I patched the find method to:

```
def set_user
  @user = User.includes(:reviews).find(params[:id].delete('@'))
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I ended up solving this:

#### 1) Include the `@` in the `friendly_id` slug

To do this I had to patch the `normalize` function which strips it out when calling `.parameterize`

```
# overwrite normalize function because it's stripping 
# out '@' when calling .parameterize
def normalize_friendly_id(value)
  "@" + value.to_s.parameterize
end
```

#### 2) Regenerate all slugs

There are various methods, I went with deleting the slug and generating it again.

```
User.each do |u|
  u.update_attribute(:slug, nil)
end

User.find_each(&:save)
```

Have in mind `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` & if you overwrote it.

#### 3) Routing Constraint

I wrapped my User routes in a constraint:

```
constraints(Constraints::UserProfile.new) do
  resources :users,
  ....
end
```

which looks like this:

```
module Constraints
  class UserProfile
    def matches?(request)
      if request.path.match? /\/@(.*)/
        slug = request.path.split('/')[1]
        User.where(slug: slug).exists?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Voilà.